# Problema al generar reporte JasperReport en JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

Cuando intento generar un reporte me sale que el "El documento no tiene paginas", este es el código con el que lo genero.

```
public class Reporte {    

 public void generarReporte() throws JRException{

    try{

      HashMap parametro = new HashMap();
      parametro.put("","");

      JasperReport reporte = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("report1.jrxml");    

      JasperPrint jasperPrint  = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte,parametro);
      JasperViewer view =  new JasperViewer(jasperPrint,false);
      view.setVisible(true);
    } catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error: "+ex);
    }

 }

}
```

Comment: Seria bueno que colocaras el error que te da para tener una idea de lo que esta sucediendo

Comment: No me da un error como tal, solo me aparece una ventana que dice  "el documento no tiene paginas"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese mensaje sale cuando el reporte no tiene resultados que mostrar, es decir no hay datos según lo solicitado. En tu código puedo notar que no especificas el origen de datos que utilizará para cargar los datos en el JasperPrint. Por ejemplo si los datos provienen de una base de datos debes colocar el objeto Connection, así:

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint  = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte,parametro,con);
```

Suponiendo que `con` es el nombre del objeto Connection que usaras. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: por el momento no uso bases de datos, pero ya logre arreglarlo